# Htaccess rewrite rule joomla 3

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, joomla3.8

I want to make a rewrite rule to change old url to new url like this:

From
https://www.website.com/apple/something
To
https://www.website.com/orange/something

the something-part could be anything, I just want to exchange the word "apple" to "orange" in all links with apple in it.

I have a joomla 3.8 website and I've tried all sorts of rewrite rules in the joomla htaccess file but nothing works. I don't know how to write the rule and where to put it in the htaccess-file.

Latest fail:
RewriteRule ^/apple(.*) /orange$1 [L,R=301]

My joomla htaccess looks like this:

```
##
# @package      Joomla
# @copyright    Copyright (C) 2005 - 2013 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.
# @license      GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
##
##
# READ THIS COMPLETELY IF YOU CHOOSE TO USE THIS FILE!
#
# The line just below this section: 'Options +FollowSymLinks' may cause problems
# with some server configurations.  It is required for use of mod_rewrite, but may already
# be set by your server administrator in a way that dissallows changing it in
# your .htaccess file.  If using it causes your server to error out, comment it out (add # to
# beginning of line), reload your site in your browser and test your sef url's.  If they work,
# it has been set by your server administrator and you do not need it set here.
##
#Force IE out of compabilitymode
Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=edge,chrome=1"
## Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
Options +FollowSymLinks
## Mod_rewrite in use.
RewriteEngine On
## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.
# If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
# This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
#
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root homepage
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
#
## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.
## Begin - Custom redirects
## End - Custom redirects
##
# Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
# is not directly related to physical file paths.
# Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root).
##
# RewriteBase /
## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
#
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the request is for something within the component folder,
# or for the site root, or for an extensionless URL, or the
# requested URL ends with one of the listed extensions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|vcf|raw))$ [NC]
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
#
## End - Joomla! core SEF Section.
#Redirect admin because of session error temporarely
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following to your .htaccess file in between the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` tags: try this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}
RewriteRule ^apple/(.*)$ /orange/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: It isn't working but I'm not sure if I'm putting it where it should be.

Comment: Added htaccess. Where should I put the rewrite rule in there?

Comment: it's inside `.htaccess` and you can placed wherever.

Comment: somehow the example rule above didn't work so I thought I'd double check if I put it in the wrong place somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working with this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^apple/(.*)$ /orange/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Hopefully it will helps somebody else ;-)